# Query to view the date and time a row was last updated for table without having an existing trigger\mechanism?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I'm sure this is going to be a hard no, but I have a table that I need to know the last update date and time for one particular row, written in the past.

Is there a way to find this information? Maybe a system column that accompanies every row that the rdbms writes by default but not visible to users? Or do we need to create a trigger\procedure to record this information on a table-by-table basis BEFORE records are written? Googling only suggests that this is the case.

I don't have DBA access and can't get it btw.

SQL Server Management Studio v18.1

Comment: You are right, if you have not taken any steps to record this info then it is unavailable to you.

Comment: BTW the version of Management Studio is meaningless, its just a User Interface which could be interfacing to a database with a completely different version. What is useful useful is to post the version obtained with `select @@version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, if you have not taken any steps to record this info then it is unavailable to you. – Dale K Dec 10 at 1:56